# How to fix TypeError: 'str' object is not callable?

Tags: python, string, typeerror, callable

pic

[image: 1]

Try to simplfy the my question here, so used a,b, & c instead.

Even though I copied the tutorial's answer and run it through Colaboratoy, it still show TypeError:'str' object is not callable.

Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: You have previously done something like `print = "blah"`, which overwrote the standard `print()` function.  `del print` should fix this, or you can restart the Python interpreter.

Comment: that's why! thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you might somewhere have declared the print as a variable. eg: `print = "sample"`. So restart the session or execute `del print` command and try executing your code.

```
    del print
    a=1
    b=2
    c=a+b
   
    print(c)
```

Try executing the above code, also follow the below rules while naming a variable in python.

- The identifier must start with a letter or an underscore (_).
- The identifier can contain letters, digits, and underscores.
- The identifier cannot be a reserved word.

Here are some examples of valid and invalid identifier names in Python:

```
# Valid identifier names
_private
_private123
myVariable
myVariable123
MY_CONSTANT

# Invalid identifier names
123invalid  # cannot start with a digit
for  # for is a reserved word
```

Comment: I try execute the function del print, but it says it is not identified. So I restart the session and it works! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question title:

> How to fix TypeError: 'str' object is not callable?

As a starter in python I feel the need to answer this because nor python nor editors (at least vscode with python plugin) seem to give a hint that you may have **accidentally shadowed a methodName with a fieldName**.

Consider the following:

```py
# value field shadows value() method
class ValueWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 'someValue'

    def value(self):
        return self.value

print("value:", ValueWrapper().value())
```

**output:** TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```py
# value field does not shadow getValue() method
class ValueWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 'someValue'

    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

print("value:", ValueWrapper().getValue())
```

**Output:** value: someValue

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with my code here, in that I was supposed to be calling the attributes of my Person class, but I was calling the methods.

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

    def name(self):
        return self.name
   
    def age(self):
        return self.age

    def gender(self):
        if self.gender == "Male":
            return "man"
        return "Woman"

person = Person("Hanson", 26, "Male")
print(f"{person.name()} is {person.age()} years old {person.gender()}")
```

And I had this error

> print(f"{person.name()} is {person.age()} years old
> {person.gender()}")
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

All I did to solve this was to call the instance attributes and not the methods

**>  print(f"{person.name} is {person.age} years old {person.gender}")**